# Default Preferences in a Firefox Bootstrapped Addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-restartless

Firefox Bootstrapped Addons do not read the Default Preferences like Overlay Addons.
I understand the need of manually setting default preferences when a Bootstrapped Addon is installed.

After the initial installation, I guess the only benefit of setting default preferences is to enable to reset preferences (unless FF keeps track of it elsewhere).

Question is, do default preference have to be read and set on each `startup()`?
If so, where are they going to be saved (ie where does `getDefaultBranch()` get the data from)?

Reference:
[How to convert an overlay extension to restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/How_to_convert_an_overlay_extension_to_restartless)
[A brief guide to Mozilla preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences)
[Restartless Add-ons Default Preferences](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2011/01/restartless-add-ons-%E2%80%93-default-preferences/)
[Preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been given an answer via email which I am posting here verbatim for the benefit of users.

From Dave Garrett, developer of [Flagfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flagfox/) and author of  [How to convert an overlay extension to restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/How_to_convert_an_overlay_extension_to_restartless)

> Default prefs set during runtime are saved nowhere. There is no on
>   disk cache of default prefs.
>
> On Firefox start, default prefs are read from their various locations
>   into the preferences system. (Firefox has its own in omni.ja & addons
>   have theirs in their install folders/files) A copy of this branch is
>   also maintained with the user prefs read from prefs.js overwritten
>   into it. Setting of (user) prefs changes the state in the prefs
>   system, which (eventually) is recorded in prefs.js (again, only
>   non-default pref values are saved). Setting of default prefs changes
>   the state in the prefs system, however this is not saved anywhere.
>   They need to be loaded on every start. For the old standard default
>   prefs system, Firefox loaded them on every start for you. For
>   restartless extensions you need to do this yourself. Every addon
>   startup needs to load the default prefs.
>
> You can of course use prefs without having a default at all, but you'd
>   have to hardcode the default values in your code all over the place.
>   Simply implementing a default prefs system for restartless addons is a
>   far cleaner solution that avoids mistakes you would otherwise make.
>
> As the prefs system only stores non-default prefs to disk, it also can
>   greatly improve the efficiency in saving prefs once they're put back
>   to default for any reason. For example, I've got a JSON blob in a
>   string pref. (as of v5.0 it's fairly compacted now) If a user alters
>   what needs to be saved there by changing something in the options
>   dialog, this JSON blob will be stored in prefs.js in full. If the user
>   then reverts that change, their JSON blob will be reverted to the
>   prior value. If this is equivalent to whatever the default value is,
>   then prefs.js simply stores no value and the default is used. This
>   reduces what needs to be loaded on start from prefs.js in the default
>   case. In fact, I can use the prefs API to detect if the value is
>   currently set to default and I entirely bypass loading from the packed
>   JSON user pref and go directly to a full JSON file, in which case I
>   don't even need to load from the prefs system. It's an optimization
>   that is only really applicable in cases like this, but it's another
>   example why properly using defaults can be useful.

Regarding the removal of Default Preferences on `shutdown()`

> Generally no, you don't need to remove default preferences on
>   shutdown, though there's a legitimate argument that it might be
>   correct to do so (but maybe a bad idea). To be clear, there's a few
>   separate cases of shutdown to take into account:
>
> 1) Firefox shutdown + addon shutdown: In this case you should not be
>   doing any shutdown that isn't needed to preserve data. No need to
>   unload your stuff as app shutdown is in progress and it'll do that for
>   you.
>
> 2) addon shutdown due to addon update: In this case you need to
>   properly unload everything you've loaded so that the next version can
>   load cleanly. However, there's no need to worry about default
>   preferences here, generally. The new version's will be loaded and
>   overwrite the old. (unless a default has been removed, in which case
>   that will linger in memory doing nothing)
>
> 3) addon shutdown due to addon disable: Leaving default prefs loaded
>   here hurts nothing other than the tiny amount of memory they take up.
>   If you have a lot of prefs I guess unloading them might be warranted,
>   however this is not a use case that is going to come up very often. I
>   wouldn't worry about unloading prefs at all unless you either have way
>   too many prefs or prefs so large that you're getting warnings in the
>   browser error console about them being too big. (in which case you
>   should fix that)
>
> Even if it might be a good idea to clean up default prefs on shutdown,
>   deleting a default pref that has a user pref might break things. I
>   suggest just leaving them alone.